# Everytime i run this recrusion algorithm, my variable is set to 0 how to solve it

Tags: java, variables, recursion, reset

I wrote an algorithm that calculates the number of actions needed to be in order to get to the number. But every time the recursive function is happening , the "temp" variable reset to be 0.

How can i solve this problem that it won't reset every time and it will consists the counting value?

```
public static int minOps(int x, int y) {
    int temp = 0;
    if (y <= x)
        return temp;
    if (y / 2 > x) {
        temp++;
        return minOps(x, y / 2);
    } else {
        minOps(x, y - 1);
        temp++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You could just pass the temp variable into the function along with x and y

Answer (score 9):

By **eliminating** `temp` completely (you don't need it). Like,

```
public static int minOps(int x, int y) {
    if (y <= x) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (y / 2 > x) {
        return 1 + minOps(x, y / 2);
    }
    return 1 + minOps(x, y - 1);
}
```

And use braces even when they're optional.

Comment: *"And use braces even when they're optional."* Best tip ever 1+